# Pandas to_json with groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, to-json

For a `pandas` dataframe like this

```
key    val1   val2
a      a1     a2
a      b1     b2
c      c1     c2
```

How can I convert it to the following `json`? Need to group on 'key' and use its values as the keys in the json:

```
{
 "a":[{"val1":"a1",
       "val2":"a2"},
      {"val1":"b1",
       "val2":"b2"}],
 "c":[{"val1":"c1",
       "val2":"c2"}]
}
```

Tried using `df.groupby('key').apply(lambda x: x.to_json(orient='records'))` but it includes the key in the json array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [.to_dict()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with "records"

```
df = df.groupby("key")[["val1", "val2"]].apply(lambda x: x.to_dict(orient="records")).to_json()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
{'a': [{'val1': 'a1', 'val2': 'a2'}, {'val1': 'b1', 'val2': 'b2'}], 'c': [{'val1': 'c1', 'val2': 'c2'}]}
```